# "ourselves" vs "us"

Tags: grammar, ellipsis, subjects, reflexive-pronouns, direct-objects

> It's also a time to relax our mind and discover ourselves
>   when we stroll around unplanned and without any
>   specific purpose.

Could somebody tell me why the writer used *ourselves* instead of *us?* I think *ourselves* is a reflexive pronoun that should reflect back on a subject. But I see no subject here that means the same thing as *ourselves.*

Comment: Read [**here**](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/pronouns/reflexive-pronouns) about _reflexive pronouns._ (I have edited your question to introduce a space between a period and the first word in the next sentence. Remember, punctuation is important!)

Comment: #P. E. Dant  I know the basic rules of  reflexive pronoun. As per the rule we use reflexive when subject and object are the same. But Look at my  above sentence, where is the subject  of (ourselves) ?  Please Ans this considering my sentence.

Comment: No pronoun, including a reflexive pronoun, can take an object or a subject. You need the _referent_ for _ourselves._ Consider the simpler form _It is time to discover ourselves._ This sentence means _It is time (for us) to discover ourselves._

Comment: Also, I think you can add "for us" after "time" without any difference in meaning

Comment: @P.E.D From the link you provided: *as a direct object when the object is the same as the subject of the verb".* So there are multiple conceptions of *subject* in various grammars.

Comment: @JimReynolds My hope was to help the OP discover the answer himself. In the sense that he used "subject," _referent_ would, I hoped, lead him to that answer on his own.

Comment: @P.E.D I'm sure it did or would, as I essentially expanded the essence of your comment into my answer. Just making a fine point for its own sake.

Answer (score 3):

The "subject" that *ourselves* references is implied in the sentence.

We could write the idea this way

> It's also a time for us to relax our mind and discover ourselves when we stroll around unplanned and without any specific purpose.

We can sometimes leave out parts of a sentence that are "needed", because our listener can infer or understand that those parts are "there".

The rules that describe when and how we can do this are complex. The relevant grammar topics include "linguistic ellipsis" and "substitution".

As I was reminded in the Language Overflow chatroom, these pronouns are not always used reflexively. Consider *She did it herself.* Notice that *she* didn't do anything to *herself.* Some linguists call these *emphatic pronouns.*